# How to force Zustand to work on client side only?

Tags: next.js, zustand

I have been writing a persist middleware (I know there is built-in one but I want to write from scratch for an interview task).
When I use middleware to write items in store to Local Storage, there is no problem, but when I want to initialize items from Local Storage when app is started running, I get hydration error. Is there anyway to force Zustand to work client side only or at least my middleware?

```
// Zustand
const localStorage: Middleware<Store> = (config) => (set, get, api) =>
  config(
    (args) => {
      set(args)
      if (isRunningInBrowser) LocalStorage.Modify(get().items)
    },
    get,
    api,
  )

export const useStore = create<Store>(
  localStorage((set) => ({
    items: [...(isRunningInBrowser ? LocalStorage.Read() : [])]
  )}
)

// Class
import { type Item } from '@/store'

export class LocalStorage {
  public static Modify(items: Item[]) {
    localStorage.setItem('itemsStorage', JSON.stringify(items))
  }

  public static Read() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('itemsStorage')) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsStorage') || '[]')
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
}
```